# Summary group differences following ANOVA in R

Tags: r

I've just finished running a one-way ANOVA test through the following code:

```
Anova_Results <- aov(TotalComm ~ treatment, data = ANOVA_Relationship_Subset)
summary(Anova_Results)
```

How would I then make an APA publication-worthy table that looks like this: 
[image]

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(RELATIONSHIP = c(4.33333349227905, 1, 4.33333349227905, 
3.33333325386047, 4.83333349227905, 3), TotalComm = c(279.166687011719, 
250, 275, 312.5, 291.666687011719, 237.5), treatment = c("Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control"), beep = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use R Markdown and `knit::kable()` to print tables to Microsoft Word. Therefore, we can summarize a data frame with `dplyr::summarise()` to create means, standard errors, and confidence intervals for cells in an ANOVA analysis.

A simple example using Crompton's 1947 Toothgrowth data looks like this:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Printing an APA style table

This is an R Markdown document. 

    ```{r anovaTable, echo = FALSE}
    library(datasets)
    data(ToothGrowth)
    library(knitr)
    library(dplyr)
    ToothGrowth %>% group_by(dose,supp) %>%
         summarise(n = n(),mean = mean(len), 
                   sd = sd(len), 
                   se = sd / sqrt(n),
                   lcl = mean - se*qt(.975,n), 
                   ucl = mean + se*qt(.975,n)) -> theTable

```

`r kable(theTable)`
````

When knit to Microsoft Word output, the resulting table initially looks like this.

[image]

After a bit of hand editing, the table looks like this.

[image]

I'll leave use of the `kableExtra` package to enhance the output table programmatically as an exercise for the reader.

Using the data from the original post, the R Markdown and resulting output look like this.

````
```{r opAnovaTable, echo = FALSE}

data <- structure(list(RELATIONSHIP = c(4.33333349227905, 1, 4.33333349227905, 
                                        3.33333325386047, 4.83333349227905, 3), TotalComm = c(279.166687011719, 
                                        250, 275, 312.5, 291.666687011719, 237.5), treatment = c("Control", 
                                   "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control"), beep = c(1, 
                                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))

data %>% group_by(treatment) %>%
     summarise(Count = n(),
               Mean = mean(TotalComm), 
               SD = round(sd(TotalComm),3), 
               SE = round(SD / sqrt(Count),3), 
               Lower = round(Mean - SE*qt(.975,Count),3), 
               Upper = round(Mean + SE*qt(.975,Count),3)) -> theTable

```

### Table 2: data from original post 
`r kable(theTable)`
````

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: I've done this:  ```ANOVA_Relationship_Subset %>% group_by(treatment) %>%
         summarise(n = n(),mean = mean(TotalComm), 
                   sd = sd(TotalComm), 
                   se = sd / sqrt(n),
                   lcl = mean - se*qt(.975,n), 
                   ucl = mean + se*qt(.975,n)) -> theTable``` but receive the following error code: ```Error in ANOVA_Relationship_Subset(.) : could not find function "ANOVA_Relationship_Subset"``` What may be going on?

Comment: @PhilJameson - absent reproducible data in your question, I'm not going to be able to reproduce this error. I noticed you posted an answer that uses different column names. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Ah, good point. I'm on a call with the fam atm, but as soon as I get off in a bit I'll add my data. Thanks Len!

Comment: @PhilJameson - see updated answer that includes the data you posted It would be a bit more interesting if your `dput()` included multiple treatment categories.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
ANOVA_Relationship_Subset_sum <- ANOVA_Relationship_Subset %>%
  dplyr::group_by(treatment) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(
    n=n(),
    mean=mean(RELATIONSHIP), 
    `std. dev` = sd(RELATIONSHIP)
  )
ANOVA_Relationship_Subset_sum
```